# How to base64 encode a guid in sql server

Tags: sql-server, base64, guid

How can I re-create the following c# code with a uniqueidentifier datatype in sql server 2005.

```
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(guid.ToByteArray());
```

I have tried several examples I came across on the internet such as http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=554886 but they all return strings much longer than the .net function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample in your link works if you pass in a uniqueidentifier

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(guid.ToByteArray());
Console.WriteLine(guid);
Console.WriteLine(encoded);
```

for

```
32705fe3-cedd-4bfd-a881-9dd11e543f9e
419wMt3O/UuogZ3RHlQ/ng==
```

And

```
declare @guid uniqueidentifier = '32705fe3-cedd-4bfd-a881-9dd11e543f9e'
select dbo.f_BinaryToBase64(@guid)
```

for

```
419wMt3O/UuogZ3RHlQ/ng==
```

Answer (score 1):

my guid's was in a nvarchar(MAX) column named 'guid' and looked like this

```
 {4A449FE1-8989-4D69-935C-9E918244DEED}
```

Taking a few steps i.e. showing my working.  I added three columns to my table guidreal, guidbinary, guidbase64. I realise this can be compressed :-).

1.

```
update [Database].[dbo].[LotofRecords]
set guidreal =  Cast(Replace(Replace([guid],'{',''),'}','') AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

2.

```
update [Database].[dbo].[LotofRecords]
set guid_binary =  cast(guidreal as VARBINARY(MAX))
```

3.

```
update [Database].[dbo].[LotofRecords]
set guidBase64 =   cast(N'' as XML).value(
              'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("guid_binary")))'
              ,'nvarchar(25)'
              )
```

which gave me

```
4Z9ESomJaU2TXJ6RgkTe7Q==
```

decode back to varbinary using

```
select cast(N'' as XML).value(
              'xs:base64Binary(sql:column("guidbase64"))'
              ,'varbinary(max)'
              )
              ,guid_binary
from
 [Database].[dbo].[LotofRecords]
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think it's not possible.
The algorithm in C# side is different from whatever combination you may find in sql part.

---

To solve this, what I recommend is to do all in one side. i.e.: populate the db from the c# side or do all in the sql part.